# Getting date from another timezone

Tags: android, timezone, android-calendar

How can I change the timezone, when I use this code to get the date?

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils.formatDate(c.getTime());
```

This returns me the date in my timezone (GMT+00:00) but I need the CET time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setTimeZone` method on your calendar to set the time zone to CET.

```
c.setTimeZone( "Europe/Amsterdam" );
```